# How do you say "What about us?" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

In English, a short for "*What will happen to us because of your decisions?*" is "*What about us?*". "*What about us?*" would literally translate as "*Quid de nobis?*". However, I guess that's not proper Latin. In Croatian, you say "*Što je s nama?*", which would literally translate as "*Quid est nobiscum?*", but I guess that's not proper Latin either. So, how do you say "*What about us?*" in Latin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"What will happen to us" can indeed be translated as *Quid de nobis futurum est?*

See for example Cicero, [Ad fam. 9, 17](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/fam9.shtml#17):

> Immo vero, si me amas, tu fac, ut sciam, quid de nobis futurum sit...
> *On the contrary, if you love me, see to it that I learn what will happen to me ...*

Comment: Note that you could also say *fiet*, in this letter from Cicero the periphrastic conjugation is required grammatically in both instances (indirect speech/question), but I think it sounds good in direct speech too.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's correct. It's implied the form "dicam" "quid dicam de nobis?"

Comment: Do you happen to know if this phrase is attested in the literature? I can well imagine Plautus using it.

Comment: If isn’t, the OLD is a bad dictionary. I found that use of "quid" there. I'm not sure, but one of the authors who was cited as source was Cicero.

Comment: I see. Can you edit it into your answer that OLD gives this phrase under *quid*? Mentioning that is perfectly enough; that's indeed a trustworthy dictionary.